# What extension is this?

Tags: plugins

I was watching a programming video on YouTube and the instructor had the extension below installed. It looks very useful – instead of just showing open apps, it shows a wide range of default and customizable items.  Does anyone know what it is?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like [SuperTab](http://www.supertab.me/SuperTab.html) ($20, free trial).

Comment: Cool. Thanks! (I haven't used extensions much in OSX).